# DUDA CON SELENIUM V4 EN PYTHON :(

Tags: web, selenium, scraping

He intentado ya de muchas formas y no puedo hacer que me funcione el siguiente código me aparecen errores como StaleElementReferenceException y no entiendo por qué si se supone con la espera explicita se esperan a que los elementos estén disponibles para su uso...
Lo que intento al abrir la página (https://www.banxico.org.mx/monspei/#todos) es lo siguiente:

1.- Obtener el nombre del primer banco en este caso sería ABC CAPITAL y guardarlo en una variable

2.- Hacer clic en el botón perteneciente a ABC CAPITAL que esta justamente en el nombre

3.- Obtener los datos del encabezado **Fin** y guardarlos en una lista

4.- Hacer clic en el botón **TODOS** para volver nuevamente a la página principal donde están los bancos

5.- Hacer exactamente los mismos pasos con los bancos siguientes (para eso puse el for )

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By  
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait  
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



def principal():
    driver = webdriver.Edge()

    # Se obtiene la página a utilizar
    driver.get('https://www.banxico.org.mx/monspei/#todos')
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)  # Configura la espera explícita


    for j in range( 0 , 84 ):  #
    
        # Espera a que aparezca el nombre del banco a monitorear
        nombre_element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f'//tbody/tr[@id = "tr_{j}"]')))
        nombre = nombre_element.text
        nom_banco = nombre

        print(f"El nombre del banco es: {nom_banco}")

        # Hace clic en el banco correspondiente
        banco_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="tr_{j}"]/td[1]')))
        banco_element.click()
        

        datos = []
        cadena = ""

        # Espera a que aparezcan las fechas para trabajar con ellas y meterlas en una lista
        elementos_fechas = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//tbody/tr/td[2]')))
        for element in elementos_fechas:
            datos.append(cadena + element.text)

        # Limpia el arreglo de datos que no queremos
        # En este caso, quita APLICATIVO SPEI y deja las
        # puras fechas con el tiempo.
        #fechas = [dato for dato in datos if dato != "APLICATIVO SPEI"]

        numero_de_fechas = len(fechas)

        print(f'Numero de fechas: {numero_de_fechas}')
        print(f"Los datos a utilizar son: {fechas}")

        # Hace clic para regresar al inicio
        inicio_banco = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id= "btnTodos"]')))
        inicio_banco.click()
    

principal()
```

Comment: Ese error significa que el elemento ya no existe. Si cambias de página o el elemento desaparece por algún motivo, debes volver a obtener el elemento.